# R, after utf8 filtering still weird characters

Tags: r, twitter, utf-8, text-mining

I'm verry new to R but i need to do some text mining on tweets. I'm trying to clean the corpus so that there are only UTF8 characters. I use the function below to filter out the non UTF characters.

```
#setup with own twitter key's and access tokens
library(twitteR)
library(tm)

setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key,consumer_secret,access_token,access_secret)
keyword = "#circulatieplan"
sinceDate = "2017-3-1"
tweets = searchTwitter(keyword,n = 300,lang = 'nl',since = sinceDate)
tweets_df = twListToDF(tweets)
tweets_df
View(tweets_df)

text = tweets_df$text
corpus = Corpus(VectorSource(text))
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, content_transformer(function(x) iconv(enc2utf8(x), sub = "byte")))

corpus_clean <- tm_map(corpus, tolower)
```

Afterwards i try to make it all lowercase but then i get some input errors.

`Error in FUN(content(x), ...) : invalid input 'Elke Sleurs gehoord op de radio. Dan viel Siegi precies nog mee. #schizo ������������' in 'utf`8towcs'

My guess is that the filtering was not done perfectly and that the function can't change '�' to lowercase.

I'm not totaly shure how the utf filtering works and what it all means. Is there a better function for it or how do i solve this error.

EDIT: 
After looking at the raw data i found that there where some tweets that contained utf characters longer than 2 bytes. 
tweetid of a tweet that contains tis problem: 858280532039397379 
data:

```
"Elke Sleurs gehoord op de radio. Dan viel Siegi precies nog mee. #schizo \xed\xa0\xbd\xed\xb8\xb3\xed\xa0\xbd\xed\xb9\x84 #gent #circulatieplan",
```

I then unsuccesfolly tried to remove al of them with regex. Is the regex wrong or can't u use regex on a corpus object?

```
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, content_transformer(function(x) gsub(x, pattern = "(\\)\\w+", replacement = "")))
```

Comment: it's not a matter of tolower, it's the encoding. can you post a repodex with the actual call to the twitter api?

Comment: I'm not shure what you mean with repodex, is it the query i made? I updated the code where you can see my twitter search parameters.

Comment: i'm talking about a reproducible example. it's basically just the code that you provide to the forum so that we can reproduce the problem that you are having. you're almost there: running your code throws me the error: Error in get_oauth_sig() : OAuth has not been registered for this session

Comment: so just post the complete code so we can get the same output that you get

Comment: But i can't give you my acces tokens so i'm not shure how i can do that. Add all the return data that twitter gave me back or what should i post extra

Comment: how about dput(tweets)

Comment: Most probably,the library cannot handle *long* utf8 (0xe0,0xf0,0xf8 groups ) which contain the emojis etc. do you have the raw json body (or a tweet id ?)

Comment: I dont know enough R, and dont know if this can be done using a regex in R, but in C you should test `if(ch & 0xf0 == 0xe0) { /* skip this ch+the next 2 characters. }`

Comment: The tweetid you gave contains a `\U0001f60e`, which is a 4byte sequence in utf8: `F0 9F 98 8E=` (smiley with sunglasses)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to filter the emoticons. After a lot of searching i found that there was a function that converts a character vector between encodings. [iconv documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/iconv.html)

```
...
text = tweets_df$text    
# remove emoticons
text <- sapply(text,function(row) iconv(row, "latin1", "ASCII", sub=""))
corpus = Corpus(VectorSource(text))
...
```